# what does undefined git ref mean in github action

Tags: github-actions

I was confused about github action.I have about 20 workflows.They are configured to run when a tag was pushed.But 2 of them didn't work.After google and read the doc ,i still can't understand it.

> If you define only tags/tags-ignore or only branches/branches-ignore, the workflow won't run for events affecting the undefined Git ref

what does 'undefined Git ref' mean? what does 'events affecting the undefined Git ref ' mean?

here is my trigger configure:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+"
```

i just want to trigger the workflow while push tags like v3.1.0

Comment: I have exactly the same question. I hope we can figure it out.